# How to find recent papers with authors from my own region

Tags: publications, google-scholar

What is a good way to find recent (preferably also popular) papers within a specific field which has been co-authored by someone from my region? The field of interest is machine learning, and my region could be constrained to 4 specific universities if that makes it easier.

(In case you wonder, I would like to source interesting speakers for a series of meetups.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general search through something like Google Scholar will often match things outside of the body and keywords of a paper, so including an institution name in a search is likely to hit on the authors' affiliations. It's also trivial through Google Scholar to select only recent articles.

Since your search is a specific field and narrowed to 4 institutions, though, I'd instead start by looking at faculty at those institutions who would plausibly be interested in the area and search papers by those faculty, instead. Departments usually have lists of faculty and their area of interest published on their websites.

Comment: Web of Science works well also. Even better is the friendly local research librarian. Too many folks don't seem to know of their existence (sigh).